# I want to take user input in string and write that string in a text file using java. But there is a problem

Tags: java, file

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileHandlingReadingWriting {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileWriter fWrite = new FileWriter("IOPinJava.txt");
        String input = "";
        System.out.println("Enter data to be entered in the string\n");
        input = sc.next();
        String i = input;
        fWrite.write(i);
        fWrite.flush();
        fWrite.close();
   }
}
```

when I execute this code and enter a string, only first word of the string gets written in the file. If the string is "This is a text", then only "This" gets written to the text file.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), `Scanner::next` returns the next complete token, which in your case is the first word.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reading in the entire line with your scanner. Try  `input = sc.nextLine()`

Comment: So then the problem will be that only the first line is processed?

Comment: Yes, the scanner will read until the first time the '\n' character shows in the input. If you want to keep reading data you will need to use a loop

Comment: Are you sure it is not platform dependant? As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) say `excluding any line separator at the end`, but not specifying only `\n` as such :/